# Gases produced by bacterial decomposition of human urine

Tags: home-experiment

I know that when urine (more specifically, the urea within) is metabolised by bacteria, ammonia is released. However, because of the high solubility of ammonia, I assume it simply dissolves into the water.

A container of urine will develop gases inside. What are they?

Comment: The 112-page report commissioned by NASA in 1971 - [Composition and Concentrative Properties of Human Urine](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19710023044.pdf) - might yield some information.

Comment: Of course it somewhat depends on what you eat.  Asparagus is notorious for making urine stink.

Answer (score -1):

Carbon dioxide and ammonia when treated with bacteria along with water vapour

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry Stack Exchange. Could you improve your answer by providing more information?

Comment: **Down voted -** There has to be more than only those two compounds in the equilibrium gas phase.